# Java array and nextInt(); do not work properly

Tags: java, arrays, random

Hello guys I am having a problem with an array and a `.nextInt();` this is causing my output line at the 3rd prompt to shift up instead of under, and seriously cannot figure out what's wrong.

I have tried `.hasNextInt();` but nothing, it actually gives me an error, so here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class birthday {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the birthday problem Simulator\n");
        String userAnswer="";
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            int [] userInput = promptAndRead(stdIn); //my problem
            double probability = compute(userInput[0], userInput[1]);

            // Print results
            System.out.println("For a group of " + userInput[1] + " people, the probability");
            System.out.print("that two people have the same birthday is\n");
            System.out.println(probability);

            System.out.print("\nDo you want to run another set of simulations(y/n)? :");

            //eat or skip empty line
            stdIn.nextLine();
            userAnswer = stdIn.nextLine();
        } while (userAnswer.equals("y"));

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        stdIn.close();
    }

    // User input prompt where you make the simulation. For people and return them as an array
    public static int[] promptAndRead(Scanner stdIn)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of simulations you want to do: ");
        int[] userInput =new int [2]; //my problem
        userInput[0]= stdIn.nextInt(); //my problem
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of the group you want : ");
        int[] userInput1 = new int [2];
        userInput[1] = stdIn.nextInt();
        int a = userInput[1];
        while (a<2 || a>365)
        {
            System.out.println("please type the number that is between 2~365");
        }

        System.out.println();

        return promptAndRead(stdIn);
    }


    // Method for calculations
    public static double compute(int numOfSimulation, int numOfPeople)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < numOfPeople; i++)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random(1);
            //Generates a random number between 0 and 364 exclusive
            int num = rnd.nextInt(364);
            System.out.println(num);
            System.out.println(num / 365 * numOfPeople * numOfSimulation);
        }
        return numOfPeople;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you expect `promptAndRead()` to ever end? It unconditionally calls itself recursively, so at what point will that stop? I mean, other than the eventual `StackOverflowError`, or a `InputMismatchException` when user gives up and enters garbage. --- That is, of course, assuming user doesn't enter an `a` value of 1, in which case your screen will flood with messages *ad infinitum*. --- Side question: What is `userInput1` used for?

Comment: why did you tag your question as a JavaScript one ?

Comment: why are `userInput` and `userInput1` int arrays? why not simple integers variables?

Comment: Yeah I am sorry for the mess, `userinput1` I added it just for a test for `userInput`.
Unfortunately the `userInput` is a given that cannot be changed and I didn't made it, I know it's kinda of stupid but I have to stick with it, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Names of types/classes should always start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!!!!!!!!!!

do this:

```
// User input prompt where you make the simulation. For people and return them as an array
public static int[] promptAndRead(Scanner stdIn)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of simulations you want to do: ");
    int[] userInput =new int [2]; //CHANGE THIS TO 1?
    userInput[0]= stdIn.nextInt(); //my problem
    System.out.println("Please enter the size of the group you want : ");
    int[] userInput1 = new int [2]; //CHANGE THIS TO 1?
    userInput[1] = stdIn.nextInt();
    int a = userInput[1];
    while (a<2 || a>365)
    {
        System.out.println("please type the number that is between 2~365");
    }


    System.out.println();

    return(userInput);

}
```

To return the array

Let me know!

Comment: @FocusOnly Have you tried debugging your program before posting it here?

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't think you can do it there with that `userInput`, I am saying this because the methodology of doing this program is quite arcane.

You are then calling 2 arrays at prompting, I wonder if you might change that to one what will change such as:

```
// User input prompt where you make the simulation. For people and return them as an array
public static int[] promptAndRead(Scanner stdIn)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of simulations you want to do: ");
    int[] userInput =new int [2]; //CHANGE THIS TO 1?
    userInput[0]= stdIn.nextInt(); //my problem
    System.out.println("Please enter the size of the group you want : ");
    int[] userInput1 = new int [2]; //CHANGE THIS TO 1?
    userInput[1] = stdIn.nextInt();
    int a = userInput[1];
    while (a<2 || a>365)
    {
        System.out.println("please type the number that is between 2~365");
    }


    System.out.println();

    return promptAndRead(stdIn);

}
```

As also the `return promptAndRead(stdIn);` might be part of the problem

Don't know though just trowing suggestions at Markov ;)